# Decrease privilege in a bash script

Tags: bash, permissions, launcher, sudo

Is it possible to call from a bash script, run as sudo, another script with normal user privileges?

Another option would be to run a specific command as a normal user but the whole script would be run as superuser.

P.S. What I want to do is to customize the Launcher from within an installation script that has to be run as sudo.

Comment: @Zanna Isn't that the other way around, to *increase* privileges?

Comment: @Zanna Ah, I see. But there's a catch to `sudo -u username command`, see my answer below. So just `su -u username -c command` might be worth a look.

Comment: @HenningKockerbeck nice, upvoted :)

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways. If you just have to execute one command without any parameters, you can use `sudo -u <username>`

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami
sudo -u otheruser whoami
whoami
```

But if you need to execute multiple commands, a commands with parameters or anything with whitespace in it, that method doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash
ls /some/dir
sudo -u otheruser ls /some/dir # not working as expected
ls /some/dir
```

It also doesn't help to quote the command like `sudo -u otheruser "ls /some/dir"`.

In those cases, you can just plainly switch the user with `su`

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami; ls /some/dir
su otheruser -c "whoami; ls /some/dir"
whoami; ls /some/dir
```

Comment: I can't use the "-u" parameter in su

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried it but it seems that has no effect

Comment: @Joe I just tested the example script with `su` I outlined above again, it does exactly what it's supposed to do. What's the output of `whoami` on the one hand and `su otheruser -c "whoami"` on the other hand? If you start the script with sudo, the first one should give "root", the second one the name of the non-privileged user (in the example, "otheruser").